# Do I need to version sfdx-config.json?

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm in the process of converting a repository to the new DX layout. During that process, the directory `.sfdx` with the file `sfdx-config.json` was created somehow and now I'm not sure if I should version it. It looks like it is only some configuration for my local setup so I tend to add this file to `.gitignore`:

```json
{
    "defaultusername": "MyProject",
    "defaultdevhubusername": "MyProject"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is: no.
This file is a configuration for a given machine and/or user.

Comment: As I thought. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Semmel More directly, you should *not* commit this file, as it would cause issues for other developers using the repo.

Comment: Indeed, do not commit anything under the .sfdx folder.